# Adobe Animate, how to reference nested HTML5 movieclips using a variable

Tags: html, variables, movieclip, adobe-animate

In Animate HTML5 canvas I have a bunch of sequentially numbered movieclip instances I want to stop playing using a repeat loop.  The basic syntax is:

```
this.data_rings.ring1.stop()
```

My problem is I can't determine how to refer to the clips using a variable. Trying variations of the following has no effect:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
    theClip = "data_rings.ring" + i;
    this.theClip.stop();
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with scope but don't know what to change. Any suggestion for how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer in the Adobe forums, for anyone that's interested.
Use the drawstart event and bracket notation:

```
stage.on("drawstart", function(e)  
{  
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)  
          this.data_rings["ring" + i].stop();  
}, this, true);
```